# Kotlin: How do you read a value from XML that isn't text?

Tags: xml, kotlin, openweathermap

I'm using the open weather API and downloading 5 days worth of three hour forecast data.
Given a line of XML:

```
<location altitude="0" latitude="51.4539" longitude="-3.1694" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="2640496"/>
```

How would I extract the values that are assigned? From this line specifically, I want the geobaseid value.

I'm using an XMLPullparserFactory to parse the data from the xml and in the past have used .TEXT to get the text but this isn't text. Is there a way to retrieve the data I want?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try using `getAttributeValue` function https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: No but I will try that now, thank you